# Routes dont work in playframework 2.5

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework, routes

I am developing in playframework 2.5, but the router dont work.

**routes**

```
GET     /login         controllers.Application.login()
POST    /login         controllers.Application.authenticate()
```

**Crontroller**

```
package controllers;

import play.data.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import views.html.login;


public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result login() {
        return ok(
            login.render(
                Form.form(Login.class)
            )
        );
    }

    public static Result authenticate() {
        Form<Login> loginForm = Form.form(Login.class).bindFromRequest();
        return ok();
    }

}
```

**The Result**

[image: Output]

I use *intellij*

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: Is controllers.Application.login() static method? Should be.

Comment: yes, you can see in controller.

Comment: @Krzysiek, in new version of play, the method of controllers must not static. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In version 2.5 of Play Framework, does not exists method static for actions.

Replace for:

```
package controllers;

import play.data.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import views.html.login;


public class Application extends Controller {

    public Result login() {
        return ok(
            login.render(
                Form.form(Login.class)
            )
        );
    }

    public Result authenticate() {
        Form<Login> loginForm = Form.form(Login.class).bindFromRequest();
        return ok();
    }

}
```